# What do I modify in the code in order for it to work in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5

```html
credit_num = input("Enter the credit card number: ").replace(" ", "")
tot1 = 0 
tot2 = 0 

for i in credit_num[-1::-2]:
    tot1 += int(i)

for i in credit_num[-2::-2]:
    tot2 += sum(int(x) for x in str(int(i)*2))

rem = (tot1 + tot2) % 10

if rem == 0:
    print("The entered numbers are valid.")
else:
    print("The entered numbers are not valid.")
```

This works in Python 3.5. What do I modify in order for it to work in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `input()` with `raw_input()` and change the print function calls to print statements or you can import `print_function` from `__future__` as @BrenBarn suggests, e.g.:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

credit_num = raw_input("Enter the credit card number: ").replace(" ", "")
tot1 = 0 
tot2 = 0 

for i in credit_num[-1::-2]:
    tot1 += int(i)

for i in credit_num[-2::-2]:
    tot2 += sum(int(x) for x in str(int(i)*2))

rem = (tot1 + tot2) % 10

if rem == 0:
    print("The entered numbers are valid.")
else:
    print("The entered numbers are not valid.")
```

Comment: The print calls will actually work as-is, since the parentheses just serve as superfluous grouping.  But a better solution is to put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning, allowing you to use the Python 3-style print function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same script to work in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x, I suggest using the "six" module and the following code. (Note that the first two added lines are the only change I've made.)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from six.moves import input

credit_num = input("Enter the credit card number: ").replace(" ", "")
tot1 = 0
tot2 = 0

for i in credit_num[-1::-2]:
    tot1 += int(i)

for i in credit_num[-2::-2]:
    tot2 += sum(int(x) for x in str(int(i)*2))

rem = (tot1 + tot2) % 10

if rem == 0:
    print("The entered numbers are valid.")
else:
    print("The entered numbers are not valid.")
```